# Get an entry's last modified date

Tags: entries, datetime

Trying to determine if there is a method for getting an entry's last modified date, preferably date-time. Gave a good look over the docs and some searching and couldn't find anything other than the original creation date. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're looking for the [dateUpdated](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#dateUpdated) property.

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated }}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I actually just checked the Database and found the field.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel). The model has a [dateUpdated](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#dateUpdated) property which will exactly output what you want:

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated }}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is looking for an answer, noticed that this doesn't work without the date filter in craft 3:

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated|date('Y-m-d') }}
```

or date time:

```
{{ entry.dateUpdated|date }}
```